# Unable to install boot repair using Ubuntu live usb

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I'm installing Ubuntu 13.04 (16 bit ) along with Windows 7 in my Lenovo Thinkpad. I was able to install Ubuntu successfully. But, after installation it asked me to `restart now`. I clicked on it. It started windows without showing boot menu. Now, what should I do to get the boot menu at the start.

This are the steps I tried and was not successful :
1. After browsing I found that boot repair has to be installed. 
   I successfully used a Ubuntu live CD and tried to install the boot repair.
   I tried the following commands -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

But, I get this error now,

```
dpkg: error: reading package into file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' : Input/output error
E: subprocess /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

how can I solve this problem to get a boot menu at the beginning.

Comment: are  you running both line of command at once? If not which one gives this error, line 1 or 2? If yes, enter one line at one time.

Comment: @Web-E I'm entering one command at a time.

Comment: So adding repo and apt list update is successfully done and then with 2nd line for installation this error is appearing ?

Comment: @Web-E Yes I see this error in the second line

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to install it from a live cd,I would recommend you to download an iso image file of boot-repair software and you can burn it to a cd or a usb using yumi or unetbootin

Here's the download link where you will get the iso image:

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/latest/download

For unetbootin for making a bootable usb:

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/files/latest/download?source=directory